# add/remove class on click, navigation li item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to find solution but i can't, every single code wasn't good for my project. Here is navigation structure

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
$(".menu li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("visible");
});
$('body').click(function(){
 
  if( $(".menu li").hasClass("visible") ){
   $(".menu li").removeClass("visible");
  
       };
  });
```

What a want to achieve is next:

- When i click on `.menu li` to add class `active`
- When i click on another `.menu li` item or on `.submenu li a`, remove class `active` from another `li` item that has that class
- And also when i click anywhere else (example body) also remove class from `.menu li`

I hope you understand what i want. Sorry for my bad grammar

**Update:**

## Toggle Solution

Modified code by:  @Sasa Novakovic (thank you again bro :) )

```js
function removeActiveMenuClass(active_element){
    $('.menu li').not(active_element).removeClass('visible');
}

$( '.menu>li' ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $_this = $(this);

    removeActiveMenuClass($_this);
    if ($_this.hasClass('visible')) {
        $_this.removeClass('visible');
    }
    else {
        $_this.addClass('visible');
    }
});

$('body').click(function() {
    removeActiveMenuClass();
});
```

Comment: `every single code wasn't good for my project` Where is your code?

Comment: A list of requirements is not a decent question for on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeeHaa ...and yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code for you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8mafko3/1/).

```
$('html').click(function() {
    removeActiveMenuClass();
});

$( '.menu>li, .submenu>li' ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    removeActiveMenuClass();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

function removeActiveMenuClass(){
    $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I just modified your code for my extra needs, little update for world to see if they want toggle function ;)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.submenu li').click(function(){
    $('.submenu li').removeClass('addclass');
    $(this).addClass('addclass');
})
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $('.submenu li').removeClass('addclass');
})
```

```css
.addclass{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu2</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu3</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu2</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu3</a></li>
        <li><a>submenu4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this snippet to your HTML:

```
<script>
var options = $('.menu').find('li');
options.onclick(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('*').not(options).click(function(){$('.active').removeClass('active')});
</script>
```